# What parameter of this sensor necessary to decide about the required ADC resolution?

Tags: sensor, adc, datasheet, resolution

From the datasheet of [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL335.pdf) accelerometer, I need to decide about the adequate ADC resolution.

If my reasoning is not wrong the output noise floor of this accelerometer will decide the adequate ADC bit depth. So if the accelerometer output has 1mV noise floor then a 3.3V 10-bit ADC would not be adequate because 3.3V/1024= 3.2mV. On the other hand a 16-bit ADC would be an overkill.

Is my reasoning is correct? How can I refer **find** such parameter(noise floor) from the datasheet of this accelerometer and make a conclusion about the adequate ADC?

---

I also cant figure out the outputs' voltage ranges from the datasheet as well:(( Is it mentioned in the datasheet what output voltages corresponds to -3g and +3g?

Comment: A better question is how much resolution do you need, rather than how much you can ultimately achieve.  What are your requirements?

Comment: 1.5V is 0g and 0.3V per g. So does that mean the max is 2.4V and min is 0.6V?

Comment: And what kind of range and resolution does your application require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I refer find such parameter(noise floor) from the datasheet of
>   this accelerometer

The noise floor is suggested in the parameters in table 1 under noise performance. For instance, in the X direction the noise is typically \$150\,\text{µg}/\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$. To make this a clearer number for your application you need to state the bandwidth of filtering you might use.

So, if you are low pass filtering the signal to a 20 Hz bandwidth the RMS noise is \$150\,\text{µg}\cdot\sqrt{20} \approx 671\text{µg}\$.

Convert this RMS value to a signal voltage seen at your ADC and you then have a noise voltage seen by the ADC.

However, you may want to read this section:

```
DESIGN TRADE-OFFS FOR SELECTING FILTER CHARACTERISTICS: THE NOISE/BW TRADE-OFF
```

It gives you a little more information about filtering and anti-aliasing. It's on page 11.